# Translation preserve parallel flats in Euclidean space?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inner-products

Two flats P and Q in $R^n$ are parallel if and only if the (shortest)distance from any point in P to Q is the same.

Intuitively, a translation $T_v:T_v(x)=x+v$ should perserve paralle relation.
That is, if P is parallel to Q, then $T_v(P)$ is also parallel to Q.

I tried using standard calculation using orthogonal projection but was unable to prove it.

specifically, I want to show that if $||x_1-P_Q(x_1)||=||x_2-P_Q(x_2)||$ then $||x_1+v-P_Q(x_1+v)||=||x_2+v-P_Q(x_2+v)||$ ,where $P_Q$ is the orthogonal projection to Q. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Flats are subsets of  $R^n$ that's isomorphic to a Euclidean space

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by a 'flat' here? An affine subspace?

Comment: @Berci yes it is

Comment: Hint: A translation is an isometry: it preserves distances between points.

Comment: @amd That only apply to points in P(since I only applied translation to P), I didn’t see the connection between distance between points in P and the distance from it to Q

Comment: Ah, yes. I overlooked that you’re only moving one of the flats. One approach might be to show that parallelism is an equivalence relation and that the translated flat is parallel to its pre-image.

Comment: @amd But parallelism is not an equivalence relation(not transitive), for example, in $R^3$ a plane is parallel to all line on the plane(since the distance is always 0), but obviously not all line on the plane are parallel.

Comment: I wouldn’t call those parallel, but that example does show a hole in the approach.

Comment: @Berci just to clarify, "Flats" here are affine space, however, the "parallel" I'm using is more general than the one that's usually considered in affine geometry, in the sense that two flats of different dimension can be "parallel".